# Fastest way to get basic information from google analytics api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My GA Account has a number(50) of profiles associated with it and I am trying to build an api which shows me the basic information like visits, bounce rates etc. for each profile.

This query gets me what I want from GA, but for each profile:

```
URL ="https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:11111&start-date=2011-07-01&end-date=2011-07-02&metrics=ga:visitors&prettyprint=true&alt=json"
```

The id is table id and the metrics gives me the information I want.

Now the problem is, I want to show all the information together. So, everytime I will have to send 50 requests to the API, which just doesn't work out. Is there a way I can get the information for all the profiles associated with me in a single request?

Comment: Pretty sure you would need to make 50 separate requests.  Might have a bit better luck posting this question on the Google Groups:  http://groups.google.com/group/google-analytics-api?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

You unfortunately will be required to perform 50 requests if you want metrics for 50 different profiles. You can easily automate this, however, by using a combination of the [Management API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/home.html) and the [Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html).

The Management API allows you to pull information about the account. For example, you can very easily pull all profile IDs and names associated with an Analytics account through this API for use in an automated query.

The Data Export API, which I am sure you already are familiar with, is the only way to pull collected data/statistics for individual profiles.

If you are concerned about speed, you might want to build an automated process that uses both the Management API and the Data Export API. Pull all of the profiles associated with your account with the Management API, then loop through each and pull the basic data you'd like through the Data Export API. Have this run at regular intervals based on your needs and cache it between runs. This way it won't execute every time the page is hit (though you honestly might be fine, depending on your traffic - I've found it to be extremely quick).

Comment: Thanks, I am currently doing what you suggested. But every time some one visits the page, he has to wait quite a bit to see the numbers. I guess, I should cache or store these to speed it up.